# Apache ignite not connecting with PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, ignite

I'm creating a simple application with signup and signin APIs. Ignite being the cache and PostgreSQL as database. Attaching my code below.
The `IgniteConfig` file uses `CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory`.

**Configuration:**

```
@Configuration

public class ignitePgConfig {

    @SpringResource(resourceName = "dataSource")
    private DataSource datasource;

    @Bean(name = "igniteInstance")
    public Ignite igniteInstance(Ignite ignite) {


        IgniteConfiguration igniteCfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

        CacheConfiguration<Integer, Users> personCacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>();

        personCacheCfg.setName("UserCache");
        personCacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
        personCacheCfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);

        personCacheCfg.setReadThrough(true);
        personCacheCfg.setWriteThrough(true);

        CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<Integer, Users> factory = new CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<>();
        factory.setDialect(new BasicJdbcDialect());
        factory.setDataSourceFactory((Factory<DataSource>)() -> {
            PGSimpleDataSource psqlDataSrc = new PGSimpleDataSource();
            psqlDataSrc.setURL("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/ignite_pg?useSSL=false");
            psqlDataSrc.setUser("postgres");
            psqlDataSrc.setPassword("password");
            return psqlDataSrc;
        });

        JdbcType personType = new JdbcType();
        personType.setCacheName("UserCache");
        personType.setKeyType(Integer.class);
        personType.setValueType(Users.class);
        personType.setDatabaseTable("Users");


        personType.setKeyFields(new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "id", String.class, "id"));
        personType.setValueFields(new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "id", String.class, "id"));
        personType.setValueFields(new JdbcTypeField(java.sql.Types.VARCHAR, "emailId", String.class, "emailId"));
        personType.setValueFields(new JdbcTypeField(java.sql.Types.VARCHAR, "password", String.class, "password"));

        factory.setTypes(personType);

        personCacheCfg.setCacheStoreFactory(factory);

        QueryEntity qryEntity = new QueryEntity();

        qryEntity.setKeyType(Integer.class.getName());
        qryEntity.setValueType(Users.class.getName());
        qryEntity.setKeyFieldName("id");

        Set<String> keyFields = new HashSet<>();
        keyFields.add("id");
        qryEntity.setKeyFields(keyFields);


        LinkedHashMap<String, String> fields = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        fields.put("id", "java.lang.String");
        fields.put("emailId", "java.lang.String");
        fields.put("password", "java.lang.String");
        qryEntity.setFields(fields);

        personCacheCfg.setQueryEntities(Collections.singletonList(qryEntity));

        igniteCfg.setCacheConfiguration(personCacheCfg);

        return ignite;
    }

    @Bean
    public IgniteConfigurer configurer() {
        return igniteConfiguration -> {
            igniteConfiguration.setClientMode(false);
        };
    }
```

**Repository:**

```
    @RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "UserCache",autoCreateCache=true)
    @Repository
    public interface UserRepository extends IgniteRepository<Users, String> {
    
        Users findByEmailId(String email);
    
    }

The `users` table has the columns `id`, `emailId` and `password`. The user signs up using `emailid` and `password`. `Id` is auto-generated
```

**Users table:**

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Builder
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Table(name = "Users")
    @Entity
    public class Users implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @QuerySqlField(index = true)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private String id;  
        @QuerySqlField(index = true)
        @Column(name = "emailId")
        private String emailId;  
        @QuerySqlField(index = true)
        @Column(name = "password")
        private String password;  
    }
```

**application.yml:**

```
    spring:
      application:
        name : application
      datasource:
        name: psql
        url: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/ignite_pg?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=false&useSSL=false
        username: postgres
        password: password
```

**Postman Response :**

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-06-29T05:29:42.022+0000",
    "message": "Failed to find SQL table for type: Users",
    "details": "uri=/service/user/signup",
    "httpStatus": "500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
    "error": null
}
```

**Docker-compose :**

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5431:5432"
    volumes:
      - "./psql-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    networks:
      - webnet
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: ignite_pg

  ignite:
    image: apacheignite/ignite
    environment:
      - IGNITE_QUIET=false
    ports:
      - 11211:11211
      - 47100:47100
      - 47500:47500
      - 49112:49112
    networks:
      - webnet

  web:
    image: application.jar   
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - webnet
```

Appclication not connecting with the `Users` table in the Postgres Database.

I'm using the code specified in the official Apache ignite documentation.

- Am I missing any configuration?
- Is it possible to add ignite as cache to an existing database?

Please help me to find the issue.

Comment: You'll have to debug this. Find out the generated SQL statements and see why they fail. Logging on the database will help.

Comment: would be nice to check the db, you could use `psql` and see if the table and records are there. if yes, then I guess a cache misconfig?

Comment: is it on purpose that you declare `CacheConfiguration<String, Users>` twice

Comment: well the best bet as mentioned above is to debug for failure event but looks like your driver and connection string might be missing something, if its with the default config, try this and please post what error do you get?
`url: jdbc:postgresql://servername_fqdn.com:5432/db_name?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=false&usessl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i have edited the code. i logged into the postgres docker container and data not getting added to tables.

Comment: @vladtkachuk I have edited the code. i logged into the postgres docker container and data not getting added to tables.

Comment: @RajVerma Please review my updated code

Comment: You didn't add the generated SQL statement, so no help from the database side is possible.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this

Comment: There are couple of problems in your code  1: you need to set the  indexedTypes with cache object, 2: You don't need The Entity to be Annotated with @Entity.  Please follow the example here  for your configurationhttps://github.com/Brijeshpant/ignite-with-java/blob/IGNITE_SPRING_DATA_WITH_PERSISTENCE/ignite-cache-server/src/main/java/com/brij/config/IgniteConfig.java